# No Tool Gun In Garry's Mod

Tags: garrys-mod

I do not have the tool gun in Garry's Mod, I did the impulse 101 cheat and got the physics gun (and all the others), but still no tool gun.

Does anyone know know a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just choose a tool from the menu and it will appear.

Comment: Tried that.. Nope. I want to override the removed toolgun! Without it I cant place light anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up your spawn menu.
2. Go to the Weapons tab.
3. Select the "Other" category.
4. Click on the tool gun.

If that doesn't work, try backing up and re-installing your game.